# Prove by Simple Induction that $12^n − 1$ is divisible by $11$ for each $n \in \mathbb N.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

Since $12^n-1$ is divisible by $11$ for small $n$ cases i.e. $(1,2,3,\ldots$, etc), I want to prove that $12^{n+1} -1$ is also divisible by $11$.

what I wrote down:

```
assume 12^n - 1 % 11 = 0
then 12^(n+1) - 1 = [(12)(12^n)] - 1
  then [(12)(12^n)] - 1 = (12)(12^n) - (12/12)
    then (12)(12^n) - (12/12) =  [(12)(12)(12^n)/12]/12 - 12/12
     then = (12)(12^n) - 12
       then = 12(12^n - 1)
    since we assume that 12^n - 1 is divisible by 11, then 12(12^n-1) is divisible by 11.
```

is there any mistakes in what i did?

Comment: Yes. How did you get to $ (12)(12^n) - 12 $ ?

Comment: Make sure you include your base case, then properly explain how you are using induction. It also is not a very good idea to use 'then' repeatedly like that.

Comment: @ChantryCargill ahh crap. I just caught that...my mistake..gonna have to fix that

Comment: Hint: $12^{n+1}-1 = 12\times 12^n-1 = (11+1)\times 12^n - 1 = (12^n - 1) + 11\times 12^n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the inductive step:

$$12^{n+1}-1=\overbrace{12\cdot12^n}^{=12\;times\;12^n}-1=(12^n-1)+11\cdot12^n$$

and both the parentheses (by the ind. hyp.) and the other term are divisible by eleven so we're done

Answer (score 0):

Modulo $11$, $12^n-1=1^n-1=1-1=0$.

Comment: thanks for a simpler way of doing it, but my course is basically an intro to proof writing and i guess they want me to do it a different way :p.

Comment: Since we're on the topic of alternative proofs, one can first prove via induction that $a^n-1 = (a-1)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^k\right)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and then mention that $12-1$ is a divisor of $12^n-1$.